# : Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure

Tags: java, selenium

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String exePath = "C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", exePath);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://toolsqa.wpengine.com/automation-practice-form/");
    }
```

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
System info: host: 'Inspiron', ip: '192.168.1.33', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_40'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver

and the browsers opens but cannot open the url also and chrome gives a pop up
"Disable Developer Mode Extension"

Comment: what's your chromedriver version?

Comment: It is 3.4.0 chrome driver version

Comment: Upgrade your selenium version to 3.0.1 or above

Comment: How will i upgrade any link u have ?

Comment: Goto this: http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.4/selenium-java-3.4.0.zip

Comment: I had downloaded this only but it wasnt working do I need to add selenium standalone server jar files also?

Comment: No you just have to remove 2.53.1 selenium jars and add jars present in this download.